# redirecting stdout to text or textfield in dart code

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-ffi

I have flutter GUI application which calls C++ DLL methods using FFI i.e. Foreign Function Interface . GUI and C++ DLL outputs some statements on console. The problem is I want to redirect those statements ( i.e. anything on stdout ) to show it on GUI in a textbox.

Any idea how to do it using dart/flutter ?

Comment: @Richard Heap : Is it not possible using flutter/dart ?

Comment: I don't believe so. Why don't you change your DLL to return strings?

Comment: @RichardHeap it is not related to DLL , even print() is flutter method which prints statements on console which is nothing but stdout. Tell me how to show those statements in a TextField in GUI

Comment: What makes you think you can capture stdout as a String?

Comment: @RichardHeap it usual practice in GUI development that we show stdout/stderr in textbox which can roughly termed as "Execution Console". It is possible in python's GUI library tkinter. It should be possible in dart/flutter also and that's what I am asking here. It is reasonable expectation that how to show execution log in GUI.

Comment: Is this question wrong and right now there is no such framework in flutter to achieve this ?